# Laplace transform operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Laplace Transform is given by

$$L(f(t)) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) dt$$

What conditions must I impose for the integral to exist? I am thinking that boundness is the only criteria we need. It would seem to me that neither continuity or differentiability are necessary.

So should $f(t)$ be at most $O(e^{-st})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace transform existence theorem states that, if $\mathrm{f}(t)$ is piecewise continuous on every finite interval in $[0,\infty)$ and $|f(t)|\le Me^{at}$
for all $t$ in $[0,\infty)$, then the transform exists for all $s>a$.

Comment: Which explains how I came up with the hypothesis…

Comment: No, I meant to say that I must have recalled it from my memory. Not your fault on your part.